# Angular material max length validation

Tags: angular

Is there any attribute available for Min and Max length validation in Angular Material 7.X ?
md-maxlength is deprecated in 7.X version and not working.
If we use ng-maxlength it wont show the counter text on validation.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) ? Several examples are there for you.

Comment: Hi trichetriche, thanks for the response, I am looking for material maxlength attribute.

Comment: Angular (and its Material implementation) relies on HTML to create validators. Since material inputs implement `ControlValueAccessor`, they implement all the basic validators. so `<input matInput maxlength="12"`> will work.

Comment: if your input type is a number, you can use max="..." and min="..."

Answer (score 6):

If you are using any of these Direvtives `formControlName`,`formControl` or `ngModel`, then you can use `maxlength` to limit the max characters.

Refer official docs - https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview